# Unzip specific file from inputstream into another inputstream with same file name and type in java

Tags: java, memory, inputstream, unzip

I have an inputstream that contains a zip file, I need to extract a specific file from this zip file, and put the extracted file in an inputstream, with extracted file type and name.
Example: zip file in an inputstream, I need to unzip ".pdf" file, and put this ".pdf" file in an inputstream with the ".pdf" file name and type.

I tried the following flow:

```
private InputStream extractPdfFile(InputStream zipInputStream) {
        try {
            ZipInputStream zip = new ZipInputStream(zipInputStream);
            ZipEntry entry;
            while ((entry = zip.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                String currentFileName = entry.getName();
                if (currentFileName.endsWith(PP_FILE_EXTENTION)) {
                    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
                    int bytesRead;
                    while ((bytesRead = zip.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                    zip.closeEntry();
                    zip.close();
                    outputStream.close();
                    return new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());
                }
                zip.closeEntry();
            }

            zip.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null; // File not found in the zip
    }
```

But it returns the new inputstream in zip format not .pdf.

Any idea how to unzip a file from inputstream and return the extracted file unzipped in another inputstream?

Comment: You can't put **files** into an `Outputstream`, that's a misnomer. `InputStream` represents the **contents** of the file, not the file itself. If you want to have a particular output file in the end, that is not the responsibility of the code you're showing, but the responsibility of the code that actually writes the result of your `extractPdfFile` somewhere.

Comment: The code you're showing should properly unzip the file. Why do you think it doesn't? Like @M.Prokhorov said, you will still need to write the file using the returned `InputStream`.

Comment: @Jorn The returned InputStream from the method is in zip format. I sent it into another component, it extracts its name as ".zip". There might be something wrong here. Could you explain what do you mean by writing the file from the returned InputStream?

Comment: @RamiKhal InputStream doesn't have a name. The other component must be coming up with it itself somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have an inputstream that contains a zip file

No you do not.  Presumably you mean that you have an `InputStream` from which zip-formatted data can be read.  This is not the same thing, and the distinction can be important.

> I need to extract a specific file from this zip file, and put the extracted file in an inputstream, with extracted file type and name.

And that's one of the ways in which it's important.  The data in a stream do not have an associated filename.  A stream is just a conduit for data.  You may create a stream that provides content from a particular file, but that's not a recognizable characteristic of the stream itself.  The type of the file's content is characteristic of the data, of course, but if by "file type" you mean "filename extension" or similar, then no, that just is not part of an `InputStream`.

A `ZipInputStream` in particular does support a higher level of abstraction over the content, so that you can read it as  a sequence of `ZipEntry`s and their associated data, but that's a capability enabled by the specific form of the data (zip).  There is no analogue for generic `InputStream`s.

> I tried the following flow: [...] But it returns the new inputstream in zip format not .pdf.

Implausible.  The various `ZipInputStream.read()` methods read the *uncompressed* data of an entry.  This is documented, and it has worked correctly for a very long time.  You have implemented an approach that will successfully extract that uncompressed data, and will provide an `InputStream` from which that uncompressed data can then be read.

But again, there is no file name or extension associated with the stream that is returned.  It's not even backed by a file.  The stream just provides a sequence of bytes from an array.  If you want to convey an associated filename then you need to do that separately.  For example, perhaps you want to provide the `ZipEntry` describing the file, along with the `InputStream` from which the data can be read -- almost like `ZipInputStream` does itself.

You might, for example, bundle that together like so:

```
public class UncompressedData {

    private byte[] bytes;
    private String originalFilename;
    private boolean isDirectory;
    // ...

    private UncompressedData() {
        // empty
    }

    /**
     * Creates and returns an UncompressedData object representing the
     * current entry of the specified ZipInputStream, as described by
     * the specified ZipEntry
     */
    public static UncompressedData fromZip(ZipEntry entry, ZipInputStream stream)
            throws MyUncompressedDataException {
        UncompressedData data = new UncompressedData();

        data.originalFilename = entry.getName();
        data.isDirectory = entry.isDirectory();

        if (data.isDirectory) {
            data.bytes = new byte[0];
        } else {
            int numToRead = entry.getLength();

            data.bytes = new byte[numToRead];
            for (int offset = 0; offset < numToRead; ) {
                int numRead = stream.read(data.bytes, offset, numToRead);
                if (numRead < 1) {
                    throw new MyCompressedDataException();
                }

                offset += numRead;
                numToRead -= numRead;
            }
        }

        return data;
    }

    /**
     * Creates and returns an InputStream from which the bytes of this
     * UncompressedData can be read.
     */
    public InputStream asStream() {
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a filename associated with this UncompressedData.
     * Typically, this will be the name of an original source file from which
     * the data were (somehow) obtained.
     */
    public String getOriginalFilename() {
        return originalFilename;
    }
}
```